# Why should G-d look at the parts of His creation?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, parashat-bereishit, creation

THis part of the story of the Creation seriously puzzles me: G-d looking at His creation and checking/judging/evaluating it. Examples:

> וַיַּרְא אֱלֹהִים אֶת־הָאוֹר כִּי־טוֹב וַיַּבְדֵּל אֱלֹהִים בֵּין הָאוֹר וּבֵין הַחֹשֶׁךְ׃
>   **God saw that the light was good**, and God separated the light from the darkness.
>
> וַיִּקְרָא אֱלֹהִים לַיַּבָּשָׁה אֶרֶץ וּלְמִקְוֵה הַמַּיִם קָרָא יַמִּים וַיַּרְא אֱלֹהִים כִּי־טוֹב׃
>   God called the dry land Earth, and the gathering of waters He called Seas. **And God saw that this was good**.
>
> וַיַּרְא אֱלֹהִים אֶת־כָּל־אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה וְהִנֵּה־טוֹב מְאֹד וַיְהִי־עֶרֶב וַיְהִי־בֹקֶר יוֹם הַשִּׁשִּׁי׃
>   And **God sa**w all that He had made, **and found it very good**. And there was evening and there was morning, the sixth day.

Doesn't G-d know what He creates and how it comes out? That would be especially weird to the approach (Rashi) that nothing was actually created in the 6 days but in theory.

So, why did G-d look at His Creation?

Comment: You ask too many questions that I cannot fully assess each one and articulate them. : ) In short, G-d does not "look". As Ralbag says, G-d knows things are as the Bible exclaims "Very good." When the Bible applies human attributes to G-d, it is not meant to be taken literally.

Comment: @TurkHill Please go ahead and explain it metaphorically. Nobody else sees it that way IIRC.

Comment: The Bible explains G-d with emotions. However, Rambam sees these as people's reactions [emotions] to natural law. It is worthy to note here that Rabbi Levi ben Gershom felt that G-d only knows the universal and not the particular. Thus, G-d is not involved in the daily governance of the world. In the same time, G-d does not walk, speak, or hear, for example, G-d did not walk in the garden asking where was Adam after he sinned.

Comment: It was a metaphor.

Comment: Look at the Ramban